# Scatter plot for variable number of rows and specific columns

Tags: excel, dynamic, plot, range, scatter

I want to create an automated scatter plot. This is the first example table based on the step size I end up measuring A, B, C, D for a specific frequency. In this scatter plot I created manually you can see I want to plot C v/s A for a particular frequency.

[image: First question example]

But I need to do this automatically as based on the step size the number of row can change. Here, since the step size decreased the number of samples increased, and now the scatter plot needs to update number of A and C values it plots.

[image: Second question example]

Is there a formula I can use without using any macros?

The relation between the step size and frequency is (number of samples of a single frequency = (360/step size)) so for a step size of 60 you will have in reality six entries of frequency `100` and six of `200` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use formulas to define chart ranges if you hide the formulas in named ranges. Combine that with the fact that #N/A values are not plotted and you can get this to work without VBA.

For your example graph you could define two names ranges as follows:

```
Name: A_100
Refers To: =IF(Sheet1!$E$3:$E$100=100,OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$3,0,0,360/Sheet1!$B$1,1),NA())
```

and

```
Name: C_100
Refers To: =IF(Sheet1!$E$3:$E$100=100,OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$3,0,0,360/Sheet1!$B$1,1),NA())
```

Then set the X and Y axis of the chart to SheetName!A_100 and SheetName!C_100

The if statement filters out all the points not at frequency 100, if you have a formula for selecting the frequency replace "Sheet1!$E$3:$E$100=100" with that.

The offset function takes the first cell in the column and expands the number of rows according to your 360/step size formula.

Comment: Hi @SMStroble Thanks for the reply. So I tried the formula with a different data set and its returns the values of the one above. That is the formulas do not update the columns according to the change in data and step size.

Comment: Never mind I think I jumped the gun. I was able to get the formula to work by removing Sheet1!$C$3 to just C3. Not sure why

Comment: You have to replace the Sheet1 part with the name of the sheet you want it to work on or like you did remove it. Either way, make sure you change C3 to $C$3, sometimes excel will change relative references in defined names and mess up the formula.